# Code skips if statement even though parameters are correct

Tags: java, string, if-statement

This code is supposed to take the input from the customer in this format "$(amount of money)". The if statement is to check that the first character in the string payment equals a '$' but this doesn't set off the if statement it it keeps reading as an invalid payment.

```
double money = 0;
String payment = input.next();
String $ = "$";
String test = payment.substring(0);
if (test.equals($)) {
  System.out.println("You entered " + payment);
  payment = payment.substring(1, payment.length() - 1);
  money = Double.parseDouble(payment);
  if ( money < sum ) {
    System.out.println("Not enough money. System terminating.");
    System.exit(0);
  }
System.out.println(payment);
}
else {
  System.out.println("Invalid coin or note. Try again.");
  payment = input.next();
}
```

Comment: What do you think  `substring(0);` does?  If you want to grab the first character, simply use `if (payment.charAt(0) == '$')`...

Comment: It's not recommended to name your variable `$`.

Comment: Adding to @MarounMaroun, from the java documentation [chapter 3.8 identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8): `The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.`

Answer (score 1):

`payment.substring(0)` returns the entire String, you want to compare `"$"` to `payment.substring(0,1)`, or to compare `payment.charAt(0)` to `'$'`.

So either :

```
String test = payment.substring(0,1);
if (test.equals($)) {
```

or

```
if (payment.charAt(0) == '$') {
```

will work.

Another option is:

```
if (payment.startsWith ($)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Substring is not advisable to match a character.

```
if(payment.charAt(0)=='$')
```

Or use regex

```
 Pattern p=Pattern.compile("$.*");

 Matcher m=p.matcher(payment);

 if (m.matches()==true) {
     /*Do operation*/
 }
```